# Identifying the densest region/cluster

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy, scikit-learn

I have an image like so:

[image]

I would like to automatically identify the dense white box area in the top left and then fill it and black out the rest of image. Producing something like this:

[image]

Essentially, I just want to return the co-ordinates of the densest cluster. I have tried ad-hoc methods such as erosion, dilation and binary closing but they do not quite suite my needs. I'm not sure if I could use k-means here? Looking for an efficient method, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could erode the image a little bit more, to remove more of the noise, and then find the contours and filter them by area. Here is what I would use (not tested):

```
    kernel = np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8)
    img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations = 2)

    #Finding contours of white square:
        _, conts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL , cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for cnt in conts:
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)

        #filter more noise
        if area > 200:   # optimize this number
            x1, y1, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
            x2 = x1 + w                   # (x1, y1) = top-left vertex
            y2 = y1 + h                   # (x2, y2) = bottom-right vertex
            rect = cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255,0,0), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

One right approach here would be to apply a large square averaging filter. If you know approximately the size of the box you're looking for, then match that size with the filter. After applying this filter, the largest pixel value in the image will be at the middle of the densest region. Let's call this point *p*.

Next, apply segmentation and connected component labeling to your original image. From your example image, it seems that the box you're looking for is connected. You might want to apply some morphological operations to make sure it's connected. You can also paint a reasonably-sizes blob centered at point *p*, it'll connect lots of small regions that together form a dense area.

Next, remove all connected components except the one containing point *p*. You can do this by finding the label at pixel *p*, and comparing all pixels in the labeled image for equality with that label.

This should leave you a connected, compact region. You can find the bounding box of this region, and paint it on your image, if you really want to enforce that the found area be a box.